# Merge Facebook likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've a problem. I've a T-shirt designing website where I want to start a designing competition. When the user posts the design on to the wall of my company's Facebook page, the person with highest number of likes will be the winner.

The problem is: a person may click the [like button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button) on my site or on the post which is on the wall of my Facebook page. How do merge these two likes?

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned, there's no way to do this. As far as the API is concerned, they are distinct objects.

From a non-technical perspective, running promotions in this manner is a breach of [Facebook's Promotion Guidelines](http://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. As far as Facebook is concerned, these are two completely different *likes*. In one sense, the user is liking the page, in the other the user is liking the post. I would suggest just keeping track of the posts and then using the API to count up all the likes across all the post, URLs, etc.